# how to redirect command output in bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm having a problem writing a small bash command. Basically I want to echo the wrapper command and redirect the output of the real command to a log file.

Something like this in my .bashrc doesn't work -- the output still gets to the console.

```
cmd="some_command >& output.log";
echo $cmd;
$cmd;
```

But the following works -- the output is directed into the log file.

```
cmd = "some_command";
echo $cmd" >& output.log";
$cmd >& output.log;
```

What is wrong with the first method? How to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean "redirect," not "pipe." Also, the `.` in your second code example is not treated as a concatenator, which seems to be what you expect (I guess you're probably coming from Perl or something?); instead, it's printed literally. Just remove it. (Also, as devnull pointed out, you need to remove the spaces around `=`.)

Comment: updated and your guess was quite correct :-)

Comment: Yeah, Perlisms will definitely trip you up when using Bash. I think the main thing is to understand that in Bash, everything you write is a string even if you don't surround it in quotes; the quotes are just there to keep sets of words together as a single string. So `echo one two three` is the same as `echo "one two three"` or `echo one       two      three`, but `echo "one       two         three"` is different because the quotation marks will cause the spaces to be preserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is wrong with the first method?

When you include the redirection operators within a variable, the shell doesn't treat those as special.  Instead those are considered as arguments to the program in question.

One solution is to make use of `eval`:

```
cmd="some command >& output.log";
eval $cmd;
```

As an aside, the following is wrong:

```
cmd = "some command";
```

You cannot have spaces around `=` in a variable assignment.

Comment: @Ashish The `&` in the command above isn't to send it in the background.  `>& output.log` is equivalent to saying `> output.log 2>&1`.

Comment: sorry.. I misunderstood question it was for bashrc which is an interactive shell (not login)

Comment: Updated and thanks a lot for your explanations @devnull! This solves my questions!

Comment: @devnull, is it really a good idea to encourage folks to use eval?

Answer (score 6):

Using `eval` works, but is bad practice for security reasons. The Right Thing, when you need to perform redirections inside code stored for reuse, is to define a function:

```
cmd() { some_command &> output.log; } # define it
declare -p cmd                        # print it
cmd                                   # run it
```

If you **don't** need redirections, then the right thing is an array:

```
cmd=( something 'with spaces' 'in args' ) # define it
printf '%q ' "${cmd[@]}"; echo            # print it
"${cmd[@]}"                               # run it
```

This is safer, inasmuch as array contents won't go through a full eval pass. Think about if you did `cmd="something-with $filename"`, and `filename` contained `$(rm -rf /)`. If you used `eval`, this would run the `rm` command!

---

To provide a more specific example, this would hose your system if run as root:

```
# !!! I AM DANGEROUS DO NOT RUN ME !!!
evil_filename='/tmp/foo $(rm -rf /)'
cmd="echo $evil_filename"             # define it (BROKEN!)
eval "$cmd"                           # run it    (DANGEROUS!)
```

On the other hand, this would be safe:

```
evil_filename='/tmp/foo $(rm -rf /)'
cmd=( echo "$evil_filename" )         # define it (OK!)
printf '%q ' "${cmd[@]}"; echo        # print it  (OK!)
"${cmd[@]}"                           # run it    (OK!)
```

...and it would still be safe even if you left out some of the quotes -- it would work wrong, but still not break your system:

```
# I'm broken, but not in a way that damages system security
evil_filename='/tmp/foo $(rm -rf /)'
cmd=( echo $evil_filename )           # define it (BROKEN!)
${cmd[@]}                             # run it    (BROKEN!)
```

And this would be safe too:

```
evil_filename='/tmp/foo $(rm -rf /)'
cmd() { echo "$1"; }                  # define it (OK!)
cmd "$evil_filename"                  # run it    (OK!)
```

---

For a more in-depth discussion, see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (on properly storing command sequences for reuse), and [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) (on why eval is dangerous).